# Use of TV show names on drop shipping website

Tags: copyright, trademark

I'm setting up my own drop shipping business. What are the legalities behind the use of trademarked TV show names? Some of the catogories of products I have for sale would be specific TV show merchandise.
Would I be allowed to use the names of the shows on my website as long as I informed visitors that I was not associated with the companies?

---

EDIT:
The servers are based in the US, and the items will not be produced by myself

Comment: Which jurisdiction will this be in?

Comment: It's a website; the more important questions are where the servers are located (if you're not sure, ask your web host) and where your customers will be.

Comment: Also, are the TV show merchandise products manufactured by an entity that has a license worked out with the trademark holders? Or are you creating items yourself to sell?

Comment: @JustinLardinois Please find update :)

Answer (score 1):

**I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.**

The purpose of a trademark is to prohibit random manufacturers and sellers from marketing products under an established brand name, without the trademark holder's permission.

Selling licensed merchandise is not trademark infringement, because the trademark is only being used to identify the product. Claiming that one is an authorized reseller of the products when one is not may be a violation, though.